# Is it poor style to use adverbs ending in "ly" in formal writing?

Tags: adverbs, writing-style

I came across this infographic which contains the following claim:

[image: dubious infographic]

> Some grammarians consider "ly" ending adverbs as bad style in formal writing.

Are there any serious style advice sources that actually make this dubious claim? What's the theory for how avoiding such adverbs improves writing?

---

I've done some further research and found that this notion is widespread, but there is little citation or authority. Where did this idea come from?

> For what it's worth, here's a blog entry that claims "Aspiring science-fiction authors receive one piece of advice above all others: Forsake the adverb, the killer of prose. It's terribly, awfully, horrendously important." 
>   — [Seriously, What’s So Bad About Adverbs?](http://io9.com/5437610/seriously-whats-so-bad-about-adverbs)
>
> To make the point about as clear as I can - using "ly" ending adverbs is BAD WRITING for fiction writers. 
>   — [Those "ly" Ending Adverbs](http://www.users.qwest.net/~yarnspnr/writing/adverbs/adverbs.htm)

Comment: I think this is Too Localised. Who are these "some grammarians", and why should we be looking to see if they have any support for their implausible pronouncement?

Comment: @FumbleFingers How do you figure that this is "Too Localised"? This is asking about formal writing in English. Unless formal writing is only localized in a small area, I don't understand. I think this would fit nicely with the whole 'usage' part of ELU.

Comment: FWIW, here's a blog entry that claims "Aspiring science-fiction authors receive one piece of advice above all others: Forsake the adverb, the killer of prose. It's terribly, awfully, horrendously important." http://io9.com/5437610/seriously-whats-so-bad-about-adverbs

Comment: or this page, which claims "To make the point about as clear as I can - using "ly" ending adverbs is BAD WRITING for fiction writers." http://www.users.qwest.net/~yarnspnr/writing/adverbs/adverbs.htm

Comment: @Souta: Because nohat is asking us to assess the credibility of what looks to me to be a ludicrous proposition. But I will admit I didn't consciously realise until now that although **-ly** is a "productive" suffix for creating adverbial forms, it's unusual in that it's [not inflectional](http://www.stanford.edu/~zwicky/why-english-adverbial-ly.pdf) (you can't do something ***quicklier***, for example).

Comment: @nohat: That last link seems to be more a matter of "advice for creative writers", where it's claimed that **-ly** adverbs are often pointless "padding". Which may well be true, and you could even extend the stricture to more formal contexts, but the implication that **all** such adverbs are invariably "wrong" is just daft.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It’s odd, but although *only* as an adverb does not appear to allow comparative or superlative degrees, ***only* as an adjective** does indeed do so. Peculiar.

Comment: Is the focus of the objection "adverbs that end -ly" or the overuse of (all) adverbs which practice can be detected by observing an over-preponderance of the letters "ly"?

Comment: @Fortiter: The focus is that adverbs of manner, usually those that end in /-ly/, are unnecessary in dialog description in stories, & that they're generally overused in formal writing. The same objection is leveled against using intensifiers (also usually adverbs) like **very** and **quite**, e.g., "_'Shorty' was 6'4", statistically {very / quite} tall for an American, but {very / quite} short for an NBA professional_". They're usually considered unnecessary or essentially meaningless by those who object to them. Context should decide, not some overly broad & biased prescriptive prohibition.

Comment: "...how avoiding such adverbs improves writing?" -- writersSE.

Comment: Where did you get that infographic? USA Today? Anyway, the advice is common about not using adverbs (probably because one sign of poor exposition is using lots of them). And so in telegraphic form for the graphic, it oversimplifies and says "don't use _-ly_ adverbs".

Comment: This is a style question. Suggest posing it at Writers.SE.

Comment: I think the concept your suggestion seems to miss is the one called "standards and practices" that guides all publishing. To write as if speaking conversationally (to the level of readers) as opposed to grammatically is a development long in the rhetorical making. And, for what it is worth, with quite obvious success.

Answer (score 8):

Some cooks hate garlic. That doesn't mean garlic is bad. That in order doesn't mean eating raw garlic before a job interview is a good idea.

The rule of thumb is "do not make up adverbs".

Do use adverbs if they concisely convey a specific quality, better than a more expressive verb would. I asseverate most people prefer an *adverb - simple verb* pair than an overly fancy and obscure verb containing given quality.

Avoid them when they cheaply replace a descriptive expression or a verb that pinpoints given quality.

Do not use them at all if you avoidantly try to replace whole sentences with them, or redundantly repeat the sense of the verb they describe. You are able to make up adverbs impunitively, or abuse obscurely occurring ones, or arbitrarily give them new meanings, but don't do it. It's bad.

Answer (score 4):

> Some grammarians consider "ly" ending adverbs as bad style in formal writing.

Grammarians, when discussing style, could certainly suggest what they feel is good. That doesn't set a new rule of grammar.

The *-ly* adverbs have a purpose of their own and when used carefully, serve well in both general and formal writing.

---

[Essentially a comment]
Beyond this, the question is exclusively in the domain of writing style, not language. (Similar style applied in any other language might have similar implications.)

Answer (score 3):

**Seriously**, I defy anyone to tell me that using adverbs that end in *=ly* is **really** an element of poor style. Anyone who does is **undoubtedly** a pedant.

**Generally** speaking, there is a certain school of thought which asserts that verbs and nouns are strong, adjectives are weak, and adverbs weaker still. These are the same people who hold that the passive voice should be avoided, and so on. While there is a germ of truth in some of this, writing that cleaves to one set of prepackaged strictures tends to become boring and predictable.

Comment: Is this supposed to be good style, because without being rude it doesn't sound very elegant to me.

Comment: @StuartF Egance is merely one kind of style.

Answer (score 2):

The key is "aspiring science-fiction authors." Science fiction was at one time a type of pulp fiction, a genre that relied on fast action with a minimum of description. It's a stylistic rule, not a grammatical one.

Answer (score 0):

-ly does define an adverb, after all.

But, looking at your source matter, I think, from the perspective of selling one's work, that the admonishment has most to do with prospective readers: multi-layered descriptiveness, even when accurate, could tend to tax the attention capability of too many of them. ...in line with neo-modern trends in writing and reading...and even thinking (or, as was more accurately stated, feeling).

Perhaps it would be best desribed as a case of *inverted literary license*: standards you may feel free *not* to follow to make your point in writing. Or perhaps it"s just a way to keep editors employed?

Comment: It isn’t at all true that “-ly defines an adverb.” It depends what it is used on — in part. For example, used on a noun, it creates an adjective, like *bodily, courtly, friendly, ghostly, lonely, namely, smelly, stately,  worldly*, plus you have some that go both ways, like *hourly, early, only, yearly*. Sometimes adding it to an adjective leaves you ***still*** with an adjective, like  *kindly, lively, lonely, madly, sickly*, and even some adjectives that are no longer separable, like *comely, silly, ugly, unruly*. Plus  *golly, belly, bully, rally, sally, tally* aren’t adverbs or adjectives.

Answer (score -2):

Adverbs (e.g. interestingly, undoubtedly etc) convey opinion which, when presented without qualification, impart unwarranted subjectivity on the reader - especially in formal writing in the 3rd person.

Comment: Really? Subjectivity? Are you sure?

Comment: This is true in some contexts: sentence adverbs like "interestingly" are not really appropriate in a formal paper (why do you need to say that something is interesting if you're writing a paper about it?). But surely it isn't the major reason for the prohibition.