# How can you exactly substitute an adverb? (Pun intended)

Tags: verbs, synonyms, adverbs, redundancy, writing-advice

Adverbs seem unnecessary, even redundant, to many editors. They suggest replacing an adverb with a stronger, more specific verb. I disagree.

Here is a sentence from C. S. Lewis's "Problem of Pain":

> We are not merely imperfect creatures who must be improved: we are, as Newman said, rebels who must lay down our arms.

In that sentence, the word *merely* has substance behind it, and the word stresses in that context how humans cannot be reduced to just one trait. In other words, in my opinion there is  not a stronger verb which can replace the word *merely*.

My questions are two:

- Should I, generally speaking, replace adverbs?
- If so, how?

Comment: Allow me to suggest that if you're taking C S Lewis seriously, then you have a lot bigger problem than adverbs. That said, I think you have conjured a problem that doesn't really exist. Adverbs modify, i.e., set limits, on adjectives and verbs. If you propose that adverbs are unnecessary, than the same must be said for limiting adjectives, which modify nouns. Lewis could have written, "We are mere creatures of imperfection...." Are you proposing replacing adjectives too? Don't look to replace adverbs. Instead, use them wisely.

Comment: Since Lewis is setting up a contrast  some word such as *merely,  only, just* seems appropriate  here. If the author were simply making a statement, such as in *We are merely imperfect creatures who must be improved*, then many writers/editors might question the necessity of  *merely* there. Note also that *merely*, like *very*, is on some people's short list of words to avoid using. And by the way, you can search the Internet for *how can I properly replace adverbs?* and get plenty of applicable returns...

Comment: In its present form, I think this would be better migrated to [Writers.se].

Comment: @deadrat Your point is just that it seems arbitrary to condemn adverbs yet condone such words as *every* and *honest*. **But** strike all adverbs from *“**Honestly, just how often nowadays** do we **not** notice **almost** every honest adverb **daily** used **so well here**?”* and you’ll be left with *“Do we notice every honest adverb used?”*, a question **still** laden with frivolous modifiers — yet one **nevertheless** which most must **needs** answer **negatively**:  “ɴᴏᴘᴇ!” Either that, or else we ran **out** of word-classes **far too soon**.

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/123483 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/88130 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/237053 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/196526 http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/8082  http://writers.stackexchange.com/a/812 http://writers.stackexchange.com/a/1156 http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/25286 http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/439 and plenty more where those came from.

Comment: No writer, good or bad, has done without adverbs, except possibly as a party trick, like writing without "e"s.  Just check any text you like of appreciable length by an author you admire. So anyone who says "adverbs are unneccessary" is either lying or ignorant, and giving advice that will hobble your writing if you take it seriously. The honest, informed version of the advice you've heard would be "don't overuse adverbs," which is a tautology and therefore not very helpful. Conclusion: it's difficult to write well, and there aren't any simple rules you can apply mechanically to accomplish it.